# how to write a script file which can run multiple nodejs program

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-io

I have few java script files which will push some initial configuration data to the database one of the sample file is shown below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('../../config/config');
var PassportLocalUser = require('../models/Passport_LocalUsers');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect(config.db);
PassportLocalUser.findOneAndRemove({"username": 'admin'}, function(err){
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    console.log("removed previous admin document   ")
    PassportLocalUser.findOneAndRemove({"username": 'user'}, function(err){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }else{
        console.log("removed previous admin document   ")
        generateUserCredentials();
      }

    });
  }

});


function generateUserCredentials(){
    var userObj = new PassportLocalUser();
    userObj.username="admxcvin";
    userObj.password="$2a$10$7/xcvxcvxcvzyPNb1XxbAKG2INj4/R.TYrn0a.k9jrLvrifiV/V6RDxhpTaht6";
    userObj.save(function(err,result){
      generatePublicUserCredentials();
        if(err)
            console.log(err)
        console.log("Credencials generated")
    })
};

function generatePublicUserCredentials(){
  var userObj = new PassportLocalUser();
  userObj.username="user";
  userObj.password="$2a$10$JzLQmIThoU4swr36KUmcAO5QK5.J529qW5saO36jzgShKJV/EfBsi";
  userObj.email="user@gmail.com";
  userObj.firstName="user";
  userObj.lastName="user";

  userObj.save(function(err,result){

    if(err)
      console.log(err)
    console.log("Credencials generated")
  })
}
```

now in order to save the data by these multiple files

I type explicitly has node fileName.js Which will generate the data

But now looking for a script which will help me to run all generators at one shot. 
ie, if a folder name generator has few file like settingsConfigurationGenerator.js, user.js ..........

all these files should run or execute using single script file please provide some pointers to accomplish it.

Comment: r u using windows r linux? if linux Go for shell script.. in shell script have all ur node command to run. And then run ur shell file, all commands will be executed.

Comment: i am using windows can u please share a sample or example

Comment: As i am a linux user, i m not sure about it. Please refer http://superuser.com/questions/373706/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-in-windows